# Is there a way to schedule Samsung Magician SSD optimization?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, scheduled-tasks

I have been using a Samsung 840 for a half year on my development workstation, and noticed how its performance degrades over time.

Windows 7 is supposed to run the TRIM command automatically, but when I run the performance optimization in the Samsung Magician software, I see a vast improvement especially in random write operations (up by 30-40% immediately after optimization).

So I'd like to have the system run the optimization every few days to keep the performance good.
The manual for the older version (3.1) says there is a built-in scheduler, but I can't find it in my version (4.1) and I can't find the manual either. 
When I run C:\program files (x86)\Samsung magician\Samsung magician.exe from a shell, it just opens the GUI - even if I give it the old /? argument.

How do I schedule this app to run the optimization regularly?

Comment: Is your SATA port set to IDE or AHCI mode?

Comment: run `fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify` from cmd, is the result 0?

Comment: Samsung Magician says AHCI is on for the drive. And the DisableDeleteNotify is indeed 0.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to schedule from schedule options it has inbuild, I used winXP schedule to run it at certain time the computer is idle or not over use, schedule at X day/time to run for an hour after that it will close it automatically, inside the program I schedule to run some minutes after Windows schedule opened the program, some time trimming takes maybe less than 10 minutes, just in case I scheduled it to be open for an hour, that will give enough time to finish doing its job.

Also I removed the auto start shortcut from Windows so it won't open when I log on, the schedule will do the job when I want it to.

UPDATE:
Since this method I guess requires the Samsung application to be opened (minimized), in some point it get lost calculating the days for schedule, I noticed at some point it was not working like it should, so optimization was not taking any effect, when task schedule opened Samsung application it was not doing the job, to fix this I made two tasks, the same for Samsung application with other settings and other that use Auto It script, so I removed the task from Samsung, once the Samsung application is opened used Auto It script to simulate mouse clicks and record the job where the optimization take place in Samsung's application, edited the time between mouse clicks and give in task scheduler enough time to let finish the process which I set it to run every 4 days in the morning when most time computer is idle.
This is the script I made:

```
Sleep, 60000
WinWait, Samsung Magician, Attach application l
IfWinNotActive, Samsung Magician, Attach application l, WinActivate, Samsung Magician, Attach application l
WinWaitActive, Samsung Magician, Attach application l
MouseClick, left,  93,  225
Sleep, 2000
MouseClick, left,  937,  240
MouseClick, left,  496,  484
Sleep, 600000
WinWait, Samsung Magician, Do you want to exit 
IfWinNotActive, Samsung Magician, Do you want to exit , WinActivate, Samsung Magician, Do you want to exit 
WinWaitActive, Samsung Magician, Do you want to exit 
MouseClick, left,  109,  85
Sleep, 100
```

Both tasks will run together, the script will have enough time to wait until Samsung app has fully loaded, then will look for the window name and simulate like you were looking for the optimization tab, will press the process and will wait to finish then close the app, if fail closing it the task manager will close it.

Here’s the Task Scheduler setup:
[image: Task Scheduler setup]

I have uploaded both tasks (jobs) + script file to Mega:

https://mega.nz/#!lso1GCYT!Xa964pMDTm34zOAe-c9j-x7JWvioa8EHDsJaRgixYpM

You could use both, in task manager just update the jobs' paths to point to Samsung app + script and you're done! 
Download AutoHotkey to let you run the script:
https://autohotkey.com/download/1.0/AutoHotkey104805_Install.exe

Note: there are newer versions you could try, that's the version I have installed and giving this to make sure the script will work like it should.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Scheduler or a built-in scheduler in the Samsung software? If Windows Scheduler, how do you schedule the GUI interaction? When the OP runs the `.exe` file, all he gets is a GUI with no way to script an action. If a built-in scheduler in the Samsung software, ***how do you access it?*** The question says, “I can't find [the built-in scheduler] in my version.”

Comment: what version you use?

Comment: right now i'm using latest for XP v4.4 it has inbuilt schedule task already but can't edit it, so i leave it there, i open task schedule to work out with the Samsung's one, task schedule open Samsung app then Samsung itselft will run after some minutes then task schedule will close the process for about in 2 minutes (enough time to let it finish its job) check screen: https://ibb.co/gwU1T5

Comment: grabb it from here: http://www.userdrivers.com/RAID-HD-Controller/Samsung-Magician-Software-4-4-for-Windows-XP-Vista-7-8-8-1-x86-x64/download/

Comment: updated instructions to make sure you got it working!

Comment: Well, I guess it’s slightly less bad than it was before. (1a) I still can’t tell whether you’re presenting a solution that uses Windows Task Scheduler, a built-in scheduler in the Samsung software, or both. (1b) Your answer doesn’t say how to access the built-in scheduler in the Samsung software (if applicable). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) We don’t really care exactly what schedule you’ve configured for your tasks. Besides, you’ve already said in your text that you’ve set them to run every 4 days in the morning. Also, the schedule information is shown in the summary view in the main window. Showing the “Task” panel of the “Scheduled Tasks” windows would probably be a lot more useful. (3) You talk about Auto It but give a link for AutoHotkey. Which one are you using?